# What organization or country would be able to pull off a successful peace negotiation between Ukraine and Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, peace-treaty

Since the Minsk II Accord was declared a failure in early 2022 there have been several failed peace negotiations between Ukraine and Russia. **[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russia%E2%80%93Ukraine_peace_negotiations)**.

The three most common problems of failed negotiations are according to my netsearch: “mismanagement of expectations; unwillingness to empathize: and lack of preparation”. **[Here](https://www.shapironegotiations.com/3-reasons-negotiations-fail/)**

Who would have the best expertise to perform a successful peace negotiation between Ukraine and Russia? Would it be the UN, the Red Cross, the Vatican, Switzerland, US, China, or a conglomerate of some of these? Or something completely different? And why would that be so?

Comment: There's no guarantee that it's *possible* for them to negotiate a mutually agreeable peace at the moment (or at any given moment). Negotiation (between people, or between countries) isn't like in a game where if you do it right you get the good outcome. If there simply isn't any possible proposal that **both** parties find more attractive than continuing the war, then the war will continue until the situation changes such that there *is* something else both sides will accept. Meditation cannot *create* an acceptable peace, at best it can only help them find a non-obvious one.

Comment: Traditionally, peace negotiations are held between belligerents of the war. Why do you think it would be different in this case? The likely scenarios are that one of the states absorb the other or both agree to stood stop fighting with terms favorable to the party in the best military position.

Comment: Indonesia’s President Joko  Widodo is chairing the G20 meeting this time. He may manage to strike a peace deal between Putin and Ukraine’s representative. If so, we must hope it is achievable. That the leaders of respective military will follow top orders. Because, the indication  so far is that of two rouge armies fighting eachother with not much direction from the top politician.

Comment: Only a compromise can prevent two warring parties, who both think that they are right, from hurting each other. This means mutual sacrifice for the benefit of the common good. Peace has to be more important than justice, because peace means that lives are being spared, while justice means that lives are being wasted.

Comment: Did I hear right? The dictator of Europe just for a few days ago commanded his armed forces (NATO) to nuke Russia!

Answer (score 3):

Your net search has missed a key consideration. For successful peace talks,

- either one side has clearly won, and the terms of the defeat imposed on the other side are formalized,
- or both sides are equally matched and *both* found that *neither* side can win,
- or the conflict is not a vital national interest for one of the sides and they look for a face-saving way out when it becomes too expensive to win,
- or a third party is willing and able to *impose* a settlement on the belligerents.

There is no clear victor yet, but both sides seem convinced that they can still win. Ukraine has held out beyond most expectations, made some successful *counter*attacks, and inflicted heavy casualties on the Russians. Russia is vastly larger than Ukraine, it is a nuclear power, and almost all the fighting has been in Ukraine, not in Russia. Russia also inflicted heavy casualties.

The Russian government seems to see a victory as a vital national interest. I cannot judge if they could politically survive an 'unsatisfactory' outcome, but Putin might fear to end like [Ceausescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolae_Ceau%C8%99escu) if he steps back. For Ukraine, victory is also vital.

No third party can impose terms on the Russians. Terms could be imposed on Ukraine by the threat of cutting of aid, but that is not in the interest of the West at this time. (If Ukraine were to counterattack into Russia, their support *might* evaporate quickly.)

This armchair analysis matches what the [FT](https://www.ft.com/content/37d511b4-a127-4a17-bd6c-260e3744a0d5) writes about the Russia-Ukraine war.